# Add Arrays of C# button Click in code in Run Time

Tags: c#

To create Button and its click event in run time I use:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Name = "btn1";
b.Click += btn1_Click;
```

But now I have an array of Buttons to create in run time; how to set each button's event - I cannot interpolate because it's not a string.

```
Button[] b = new Button(Count);
for (int i=0; i < Count; i++)
{
  b[i] = new Button();
  b[i].Name = "btn" + i;
  b[i].Click += ??????
}
```

what should I do for "?????"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind all buttons to the same event, so put the line like `b[i].Click += button_Click;`.

Then inside the `button_Click` event you can differentiate between the buttons, and take the proper actions.

For example:

```
public void button_Click(object sender, ButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if( sender == b[0] )
  {
    //do what is appropriate for the first button
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried and found this to be the better answer. Without the "sender == b[o]" and if I put array in the lamda function, it will throw an exception because the array is null when it is called.

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1:**

You can pass an lambda function, and create the handler based on the buttons index in the array like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < Count; i++)
{
   b[i] = new Button();
   b[i].Name = "btn" + i;
   b[i].Click += (sender, args) => 
   {
     // your code
   }
}
```

**Option 2:**

You can pass an anonymus delegate:

```
b[i].Click += delegate (sender, args) {
         // your code
};
```

**Option 3:**

You can specify a handler function:

```
b[i].Click += YourHandlerFunction
// ....

// The handler signature also has to have the correct signature
void YourHandlerFunction(object sender, ButtonEventArgs  args) 
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do! If you want to have the same method called for all clicks, do this:

```
Button[] b = new Button[Count];

for (int i=0; i < Count; i++)
{
    b[i] = new Button();
    b[i].Name = "btn" + i;
    b[i].Click += OnClick
}

private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // do something
}
```

If you want to do something different for each button, e.g. depending on the index, you can do something like this:

```
Button[] b = new Button[Count];

for (int i=0; i < Count; i++)
{
    b[i] = new Button();
    b[i].Name = "btn" + i;
    b[i].Click += (s, e) => { /*do something*/ };
}
```